# Why is there a little square in Firefox and on my Desktop?

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7 on my office PC and at home at my game PC, I have a little square in the upper left corner. It's about 3px wide and O really don't know where it comes from.

There are no programs I am using at office AND at home (except for Firefox, but I've killed the process and it was still there), so it can't be a program.

A little image of it is here:

[image: Square up left in Firefox and on the Desktop]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a software, I'm 99% sure. Something is running and trying to put an overlay on every application you run / start. It's like Teamviewer, which adds a new icon at the top-right area.

Try looking at your running applications with [Proccess Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and find the guilty app.
Also, try checking your system with '[sfc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'.

Comment: Theres a little button in Process Explorer that looks like a target, just to the right of the binoculars icon. If you click on it and hold it down, then the Process Explorer will disappear. Drag that target over a window and let go and Process Explorer will pop back up but with the name of the process that you moused over selected. Try dragging that button over the offending little square overlay and seeing what happens.

Comment: You can view all handles or dependencies of a process in a panel clicking on a engine or a paper icon in toolbar (generally the sixth button in toolbar). So you can locate it easier.

Comment: I found the solution to this: It was DskTwist.exe. It's a software to switch between desktops. If I switch to Desktop 2 and back to 1, its gone ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any plugins / themes that you use both at home and work?  Try switching off all themes / plugins.

You can simplify this by starting Firefox in [safe mode](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Safe%20Mode).